# IIS "Object moved to" when user-agent not included

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Enter this curl command:

```
curl -i "http://www.takeoffvideo.com/recurly"
```

And I get

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=m0fmpkgsgxhblhmzgdyj1ttv; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: 51D=634601722298776937; expires=Fri, 31-Dec-9999 23:59:59 GMT; path=/
Date: Thu, 22 Dec 2011 17:17:09 GMT
Content-Length: 118

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

Then if I add the user agent header, it works:

```
curl -i -A "" "http://www.takeoffvideo.com/recurly"
```

It works!  Anyone have a reason for this?  It's an asp.net mvc app using .net 4 and all the latest.